# how to wait connection?

Tags: java, connection, httpclient

I always got

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Invalid use of
>   SingleClientConnManager: connection
>   still allocated. Make sure to release
>   the connection before allocating
>   another one.

Exception.I tried to use `abort` after use but still remains.

Is there any way to wait for the connection to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the http client from multiple threads you need to use the ThreadSafeClientConnManager.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html

Answer (score 1):

You should call `conn.releaseConnection` after you've finished with the first request, which will allow you to get another handle to the same underlying connection for the next request.

If that's not the problem, you need to give more details - your question is fairly unclear at the moment.